# How to get a variable value from tpl file in php file

Tags: php, smarty

I have variable in tpl file as
`{assign var="por" value=$product.productid}`
How can I use that above variable in my php file?

I have tried as:

```
global $por;
```

but it not works...Please help me soon....
(note:The variable **$por have contains 3 values**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since your smarty variables are PHP variables assigned to the smarty ones *before* the template has been compiled, the variable should already be somewhere in your PHP code. Look for something like:

```
$smarty->assign("product", $product);
```